# PHP - Multiple image Upload, how to allow more than one format?

Tags: php, image, upload, image-formats

I found a free picture upload script on the webby, but it only allows JPG/JPEG formats.

How do I allow it to upload format PNG and BMP?

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);$i++)  
{  
    if(trim($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i]) != "")  
    {  
        $images = $_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i];  
        $new_images = "thumbnails_".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$i];  
        copy($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i],"PIC_FOLDER".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"][$i]);  
        $width=100; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//  
        $size = GetimageSize($images);  
        $height = round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);  
        $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($images);  
        $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);  
        $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);  
        $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);  
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);  
        ImageJPEG($images_fin,"PIC_FOLDER".$new_images);  
        ImageDestroy($images_orig);  
        ImageDestroy($images_fin);  

        echo "Resize Successful.<br>";
    }  
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Right now your code is going to upload pretty much any file. It then tries to create a thumbnail, and store that thumbnail as a jpeg. I would strongly suggest using something different than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment says you already are able to upload any type but you need it to be a jpeg to be able to make the thumbnail.  Simply do a check on the type then use that to open the image

```
    $src= $images;
    $image_info = @getimagesize($src);
    list($imgwidth,$imgheight,$image_type) = $image_info;
    if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
        $images_orig    = @imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    } else if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
        $images_orig    = @imagecreatefromgif($src);
    } else if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
        $images_orig    = @imagecreatefrompng($src);
    } else if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_BMP ) {
        $images_orig    = @imagecreatefrombmp($src);
    }
```

just use this instead of $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($images);

If you also want to save the images back in whatever format they came in as, do a similar check at the bottom instead of ImageJPEG($images_fin,"PIC_FOLDER".$new_images);

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.. is there in anyway i can check if the image, is really an image, for only allow images to be found in the browse from the form ?

Comment: Well, I think getimagesize will balk if handed a exe file or something but just to be safe maybe also check [mime_content_type](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) although the MIME type can be faked.